# Cardinality of a elementary abelian pro-$p$ group

Tags: group-theory, cardinals, profinite-groups, pro-p-groups

Let $G$ be an elementary abelian pro-$p$ group. Then we have that
$$G=\prod\limits_{\mathfrak{m}}C_p$$
where $\mathfrak{m}$ is a cardinal. We have this as a direct consequence of Theorem 4.3.8. from Profinite Groups, Luis Ribes Pavel Zalesskii:

[image]

We also know that $G$ is a profinite group. So it can be described as an inverse limit of finite groups:
$$G=\lim\limits_{\substack{\leftarrow\\ i\in I}} G_i$$

I want to show that $\mathfrak{m}=|I|$.

I was thinking about using that:  When $G$ is an infinite profinite group, it follows from Theorem 2.1.3 (from Profinite Groups, Luis Ribes Pavel Zalesskii) that the cardinal of any fundamental system of neighborhoods of 1 consisting of open subgroups is the same. But I am struggling to reach a conclusion.

Comment: You'll need some additional assumption, since we can make $I$ as large as we like by adding many duplicate copies of each group in the inverse limit.

Comment: No, $I$ could be arbitrary large, and $G$ small. For instance if $I=A\sqcup B$ with $a\le b$ for all $a\in A$, $b\in B$, the projective limit over $I$ is the projective limit over $B$, so $A$ plays no role and can be chosen irrelevantly big. On the other hand since your group is explicitly given as a product, you can get a projective limit description over a set of cardinal $\max_i m(i)$.